# Combo Box in vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using a combo box with 20 numbers inside (from 1 to 20) each to represent a number of a date and time text box to be visible in another pop out form.

For example if 4 is selected, then 4 date and time boxes are visible.

The problem:

Up to 9 date and time boxes are visible just fine, but from 10 to 20 I can see only one date and time box. I couldn't solve the issue and any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub payno__SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles payno.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim selectedIndex As Integer
    selectedIndex = payno.SelectedItem

    Dim selectedItem As Object

    selectedItem = payno.SelectedItem

    MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " & selectedItem.ToString() & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf &
                    "Index: " & selectedIndex.ToString())




    If payno.Text.Trim.Contains("1") = True Then
        paytime.DateTimePicker1.Visible = True
        paytime.DateTimePicker2.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker3.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker4.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker5.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker6.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker7.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker8.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker9.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker10.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker11.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker12.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker13.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker14.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker15.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker16.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker17.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker18.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker19.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker20.Visible = False




        ElseIf payno.Text.Trim.Contains("2") = True Then
        paytime.DateTimePicker1.Visible = True
        paytime.DateTimePicker2.Visible = True
        paytime.DateTimePicker3.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker4.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker5.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker6.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker7.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker8.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker9.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker10.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker11.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker12.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker13.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker14.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker15.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker16.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker17.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker18.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker19.Visible = False
        paytime.DateTimePicker20.Visible = False

        and so on until 20 ...
```

Comment: Since 10 contains a 1 and 0, the else if will never get to 10.

Comment: thanks a lot, but how do u suggest to fix this

Comment: If 4 is selected (as your example) then just loop through Turing on 4 boxes. Set the loop 1-number selected, do a select case statement where the loop integer current value turns on the one date picker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the logic you have written it is correct and it must work. But it's not best coding practice. But if you want to modify the same code. Use the condition like

If payno.Text.trim="1" then

Elseif payno.Text.trim="2" then

.......

If payno.Text.trim="10" then

Elseif payno.Text.trim ="11" then

1.But keep all the date in one panel
2. Make the panel dock to top
3. Set scroll to true to the panel

If your pop-up form's height is lesserthan the date control's top also it may not be displayed.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Untested but something like this:

```
Dim x as Integer
While (x <= Integer.Parse(payno.Text.Trim))
   Select (x)
      Case 1
         paytime.DateTimePicker1.Visible = True
      Case 2
         paytime.DateTimePicker2.Visible = True
.....



   End Select
End While
```